# SELECT query on filtered data set which contains only the latest version of a record by date

Tags: sql

I have an occupation list which will have different versions of the occupation record added over time. This means that there will be multiple records with the same `OCCUPATION_CD` and I want to filter my data set to only show the latest version of each occupation by `MAJOR_VER_DATE`.

I will be looking up the unique `OCCUPATION_ID` for the latest version of an occupation so that I can then lookup all child records associated to that version of the occupation.

**Occupations data set**

```
OCCUPATION_ID,OCCUPATION_CD,ANZSIC_ID,OCCUPATION_DIVISION_CODE,OCCUPATION_SUBDIVISION_CODE,OCCUPATION_CLASS,OCCUPATION_CD_DSC,MAJOR_VER,MAJOR_VER_DATE,MINOR_VER,MINOR_VER_DATE
1,0219D,A0219,A,"A_Agriculture, Forestry and Fishing",,Agricultural / Farm Fencing Contractors,1,12/06/2022,1,12/06/2022
2,5110C,G5110,G,G_Food Retailing,R,Tobacconists,1,12/06/2022,1,12/06/2022
3,5710D,H5710,H,H_Accomodation & Licensed Clubs,,Motel,1,12/06/2022,1,12/06/2022
4,8440A,N8440,N,N_Education,,Other Education not elsewhere classified (Theoretical training only),1,12/06/2022,1,12/06/2022
5,9523,Q9523,Q,Q_Other,,Photographic Studio,1,12/06/2022,1,12/06/2022
6,9524D,Q9524,Q,Q_Other,,Cemetery Operation,1,12/06/2022,1,12/06/2022
7,9525A,Q9525,Q,Q_Other,,Gardening Services,1,12/06/2022,1,12/06/2022
8,9525C,Q9525,Q,Q_Other,,Swimming Pool Cleaning & Maintenance,1,12/06/2022,1,12/06/2022
9,9529B,Q9529,Q,Q_Other,,Pet Grooming / Washing Service,1,12/06/2022,1,12/06/2022
10,9529H,Q9529,Q,Q_Other,,Chauffeur Service,1,12/06/2022,1,12/06/2022
11,7241,,J,,,Music Publishing,1,12/06/2022,1,12/06/2022
12,0219D,A0219,A,"A_Agriculture, Forestry and Fishing",,Fence Installation,2,11/07/2022,1,11/07/2022
```

What I am hoping is the outcome to be is that if I do a
`SELECT OCCUPATION_ID FROM [data_set] WHERE OCCUPATION_CD = '0219D'` will resolve OCCUPATION_ID `12` not `1` because the record with ID 12 has a MAJOR_VER_DATE which is more recent than the record with ID 1.

Where I've got to is attempting to filter down the **data_set** I want to only show the latest version is below. I elected to use the unique `OCCUPATION_ID` as my way of getting the latest version instead of the `MAJOR_VER_DATE` because it feels more reliable.

What I then need to do make the results of this be the table that I'm querying on the `OCCUPATION_CD` to resolve the `OCCUPATION_ID`. How would you do this? It's like a three layered query, I can't get my head around it. Thanks

```
SELECT latest_versions.*
FROM `OCCUPATIONS` latest_versions JOIN
    (
        SELECT OCCUPATION_CD, MAX(OCCUPATION_ID) as latest_version
        FROM OCCUPATIONS
        GROUP BY OCCUPATION_CD        
    ) occ_filtered
    ON latest_versions.OCCUPATION_CD = occ_filtered.OCCUPATION_CD 
        AND OCCUPATION_ID = latest_version
```

Comment: the tag "sql" is almost useless to us who attempt answers - we need to know "which database vendor" because each vendor has differences in their sql implementations. In short to get **you** the best answer we need the most appropriate dbms as a tag. Please **edit the tags** and choose the database e.g. sql-server, mysql, postgres etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with data as (
    select *, row_number()
        over (partition by occupation_cd order by major_ver_date desc) as rn
    from occupations
)
select * from data where rn = 1;
```

Or following your line of approach:

```
SELECT * FROM OCCUPATIONS WHERE OCCUPATION_ID IN (
    SELECT OCCUPATION_ID
    FROM `OCCUPATIONS` latest_versions JOIN (
        SELECT OCCUPATION_CD, MAX(MAJOR_VERSION_DATE) as latest_version
        FROM OCCUPATIONS
        GROUP BY OCCUPATION_CD        
    ) occ_filtered
        ON latest_versions.OCCUPATION_CD = occ_filtered.OCCUPATION_CD 
            AND MAJOR_VERSION_DATE = latest_version
)
```

Comment: thanks for the options in here, I'm going to have a play with the first one and see how that works out, looks quite simple

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * from 
occupations A JOIN (
    SELECT occupation_cd, max(major_ver_date) max_date 
    FROM occupations B 
    GROUP by occupation_cd
) C on a.ocupation_cd=c.occupation_cd and a.major_ver_date=c.max_date 
WHERE A.occupation_id = ( 
    SELECT top 1 occupation_id 
    FROM occupations D 
    WHERE D.occupation_cd=A.occupation_cd and D.major_ver_date=A.major_ver_date
    ORDER BY 1 DESC
)
```

Specific sql implementation could allow to much simpler query.

Comment: Be careful. For large tables, this query can be very inefficient (sorted subquery). This could be optimized, for example, if the following statement is true: "greater occupation_id is always newer" (filled by the system as sequential number).

Comment: Yeah I see that could happen, these tables are for configuration of business rules, for most of the runs of the rules, the latest version of rules would be used so could be in memory and reused, only 20% of the time would it need original rule set for an update to pre existing records based on its date created.